# Grab image from url and save it, size is 0 bytes

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I don't have curl installed.
It has been mentioned before that this code should work,

```
file_put_contents($target_path,file_get_contents($image));
```

but it doesn't for me, it puts the image with correct name etc... but with size of 0 byte.
$target_path has correct permissions and allow_url_fopen is On.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: is `$image` a file path?

Comment: Does `file_get_contents($image)` actually fetch anything? Does it raise an error? Try debugging it in parts, not as a whole.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031076/zend-pdf-display-a-url-qrcode/16031427#16031427), it may provide you with a solution ;-)

Comment: @RyanNaddy, Yes $image gets the url from a form text input, gets it as submitted. I have also tried to manually enter the full url instead of using a dynamic variable, but same result.

Comment: @Havelock, As I have mentioned, I don't have curl installed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohanLarsson, sorry I've managed to oversee that part, my bad

Comment: Try `copy($image, $target_path)` and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allow_url_fopen` is not the only criteria due to which `file_get_contents` on a URL can break. The server might be set up to handle or detec auth/user agents et al.

Firstly try to get your data into a variable and print it out to see if it is able to fetch content;

```
$img = "";
$img = file_get_contents($image);
echo $img; //for debugging..
//for running..
if(!$img) die("no data fetched");
```

Now if `$img` has data, next try to write it to the file:

```
$result = file_put_contents($target_path,$img);
if($result=== FALSE) 
  die("Error writing data into $target_path");
else
  echo "$result bytes written to $target_path";
```

The issue you are facing is that there are multiple points of failure in that nested function list you have. And while it is nifty and compacts multiple lines of code into a single line it is difficult to debug and in cases of like the one you are facing, you will not be able to easily determine which one is the offending piece of code.

Comment: Ok, it gives me this, 20418 bytes written to /storage/.../..../images/ (I modified the path just in case for this demo) but there is no file inside that folder, the file doesn't get copied. :(

Comment: @JohanLarsson `/storage/.../..../images/ ` is problematic. There is no file name. Give a full path and filename.

Comment: Alright, That was the problem, thank you very much, thank you every body else.

Answer (score 0):

it must work check `$image` and `$target_path` content that path and url is correct is good to use `dirname(__FILE__)` for `$target_path` like  `dirname(__FILE__).'/image.jpg'` it help to have correct target path

attention you must use full path for  `$target_path`

you can test this function that work with fopen it work too but is slower

```
  function Request($url,$File="",$Method='POST',$data=null, $optional_headers = null,$Debug=0){
            $params = array('http' => array('method' => $Method));
            $optional_headers.="Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Cache-Control:max-age=0\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="Connection:keep-alive\r\n";
            $optional_headers.="User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0  AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5\r\n";
            if ($data !== null) {
                   $params['http']['content'] = $data;
            }                              
            if ($optional_headers !== null) {
                   $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
            }
            $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
            $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx); 
            if (!$fp) {
                    return false;                     
            }
            $response= @stream_get_meta_data($fp);
            $out['header'] = $response['wrapper_data'];
            $out['body']='';
            if($File!=""){
                $fout = @fopen($File, 'w+');
            }
            while(!@feof($fp)){
                  $buffering=@fread($fp,1024*8);
                 // echo "***************\n".strlen($buffering)."\n".$buffering."\n***********************";
                  if($buffering==''){break;}
                  if($File!=""){
                      @fwrite($fout,$buffering);
                      if($Debug==1)echo strlen($buffering)."-->Download And Stored IN".$File;
                  }
                  $out['body'] .=$buffering;
            } 
            if(trim(@$out['header']['Content-Encoding'])=='deflate'){
                $out['body']=gzinflate($out['body']);
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return $out;
}
Request($target_path,$image,'GET');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting your code up and add some basic error handling, this way you can perhaps do somthing instead of just writing 0 bytes to a file in case of error:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$target_path = "./some_path/";
$new_img = "new_image.jpg";

if(file_exists($target_path)){
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    if(strlen($img) >=1){
        file_put_contents($target_path . $new_img, $img);
    }else{
        echo 'Error fetching $image';
    }
}else{
    echo '$target_path not found';
}
?>
```